# Who is user 6226?

Tags: linux, centos, permissions, filesystems, drupal

In a Drupal installation on CentOS, there are many folders with the following permission:

```
drwxr-xr-x  8    6226    6226 4096 Jan  7 21:46 cck
```

The user/group 6226 was not created by me. How come there is such a user/group? Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[CCK](http://drupal.org/project/cck) is a plugin.  Did you perhaps download the tar file and extract it while logged in as root?   If so the permissions in the archive would be used on the filesystem when extracted.

Comment: Who installs modules by extracting tarballs anymore?  Get http://drupal.org/project/drush

Comment: drush might not be an option to people who are not using php 5.

Answer (score 3):

To improve security, one normally installs subsystems like Drupal with their own uid/gid.  The bug here is that the package failed to create the relevant user and group entries (or, if it was a tarball instead of a distribution package, that you haven't run some post-install script).

Answer (score 1):

6226:6226 permission happens when you are running tar or drush as root. Try running it as a non-root user who is part of the www-data (or whatever your apache user is). Doing this way all files will have ownership as user:www-data

Comment: I run Drush as regular user via sudo and have the same problem as above, which is unfortunate.